# What encoding is expected for Node.js source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

I’ve done some Google searches, but I get results related to encoding strings or files.

Can I *write* my Node.js JavaScript source code in UTF-8? Can I use non-ASCII characters in comments, strings, or as variable names?

ECMA-262 seems to [require UTF-16 encoding](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-6), but Node.js won’t run a UTF-16 encoded `.js` file. It will, however run UTF-8 source and correctly interpret non-ASCII characters.

So is this by design or by “accident”? Is it specified somewhere that UTF-8 source code is supported?

Comment: I've never given this a second though, but I constantly use UTF-8 for everything I do and never had a problem.

Comment: I expect that it's not so much a Node.js thing, but a V8 thing.

Comment: I was hoping someone could point to, say, Node.js or V8 documentation that says what source encodings are allowed. (Python example: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). Yeah, I can and did futz around and see what works, but I want a more concrete answer.

Comment: You're linking to a very old version of the spec (3rd rev. is from 1999, we just hit 6th rev. last June). The current version is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-source-text). The requirement is "unicode" (with, by convention, ASCII being a subset of unicode, since the lower 127 codepoints in unicode are the same as the ASCII encoding specifies)

Comment: Hi @Nate , it seems some years have past from when you asked this question. I'm seeking for something like the Python example you wrote in the comment. Had you found a concrete answer in the meanwhile?

Comment: The answer from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is correct. The current version now is [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-source-code). It says it must be Unicode “regardless of the external source text encoding”. That means it’s a Node implementation detail. I can’t find the requirement in Node.js but of course UTF-8 is the de-facto standard encoding now (even moreso than it was in 2012 when I asked the question.) We use UTF-8 for all Node.js code at my company and it has worked well.

Comment: Thank you @Nate , we too use UTF-8, my target now is to avoid bidirectional UNICODE text in order to avoid _trojan source_ security holes.

Comment: ECMA-262: "The actual encodings used to store and interchange ECMAScript source text is not relevant to this specification"
https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-source-code
What you read about UTF-16 is probably about the internal representation of strings (inside memory),that's totally unrelated to the encoding of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

UTF-8 characters are valid javascript variable names. Go ahead and encode UTF-8.

Comment: Unicode characters and UTF-8 encoding are different things. The standard actually seems to require UTF-16, not UTF-8 (but that doesn’t seem to be true in practice). It’s nice to have confirmation Unicode characters are valid variable names though.

Comment: Although available, I can't recommend doing things like `var Hͫ̆̒̐ͣ̊̄ͯ͗͏̵̗̻̰̠̬͝ͅE̴̷̬͎̱̘͇͍̾ͦ͊͒͊̓̓̐_̫̠̱̩̭̤͈̑̎̋ͮͩ̒͑̾͋͘Ç̳͕̯̭̱̲̣̠̜͋̍O̴̦̗̯̹̼ͭ̐ͨ̊̈͘͠M̶̝̠̭̭̤̻͓͑̓̊ͣͤ̎͟͠E̢̞̮̹͍̞̳̣ͣͪ͐̈T̡̯̳̭̜̠͕͌̈́̽̿ͤ̿̅̑Ḧ̱̱̺̰̳̹̘̰́̏ͪ̂̽͂̀͠ = 'Zalgo';`

Comment: The standard says that the native text processing model of JavaScript is based on UTF-16 code units. That doesn't specify what byte-encoding is used to convert a source file to those units.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation that says that Node treats files as encoded in UTF-8, but it seems that way experimentally:

```
/* Check in your editor that this Javascript file was saved in UTF-8 */
var nonEscaped = "Планета_Зямля";
var escaped = "\u041f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0435\u0442\u0430\u005f\u0417\u044f\u043c\u043b\u044f";
if (nonEscaped === escaped) {
  console.log("They match");
}
```

The above example prints `They match`.

### Non-BMP note:

Note that UTF-8 supports non-BMP code points (U+10000 and onwards), but Javascript has complications in that case, it automatically converts them to surrogate pairs. This is part of the language:

```
/* Check in your editor that this Javascript file was saved in UTF-8 */
var nonEscaped = ""; // U+1F4A9
var escaped1 = "\ud83d\udca9";
if (nonEscaped === escaped1) {
  console.log("They match");
}
/* Newer implementations support this syntax: */
var escaped2 = "\u{1f4a9}";
if (nonEscaped === escaped2) {
   console.log("The second string matches");
}
```

This prints `They match` and `The second string matches`.