# Bower Malformed

Tags: json, bower

I'm learning how to use Bower. In an effort to get started, I've created a basic bower.json file whose responsibilty is to get jquery. My bower.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name":  "MyProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "devDependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.1.0"
    }
}
```

When I run bower install from the directory where my bower.json file is located, I get the following error:

```
bower                       EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Projects\MyProject\bower.json
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep looking for something to be syntactically incorrect. However, everything looks correct to me. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are on windows, it's quite likely you are having issue with a BOM and/or another utf8/utf16 encoding issue.

Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169387/emalformed-error-when-trying-to-register-bower-json-file/)

Try again with a text editor that doesn't do stupid things (maybe Sublime Text - I'm not too sure what's good on windows).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like unsolved bug

see link: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/783

Try using this

```
{
    "name":  "MyProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.1.0"
    }
}
```

if this didn't work try updating your bower using `npm update -g bower`

Comment: Strange. I copied your JSON above, ran bower install, and I'm still getting the same error. I also tried running bower install after running npm update -g bower. No luck.

Comment: Working fine in our project, never had any problem.