# How to install a "pre-release" version using npm or bower?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, npm

I would like to download via `npm` or `bower` dojo version 1.11.0-pre.
At the moment I am using the following package.json file but npm is not able to find the dependencies.

How to solve this issue and load dojo 1.11.0-pre?

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "1.11.0-pre"
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#a275e8237cd8be0a4e3af4d229853f317bc56873"
    },
    "description": "fe",
    "name": "fe",
    "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What if use github repo as dependence? `"dojo": "dojo/dojo"`(https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls)

Comment: do you mean adding the URL of the git directly?

Comment: Yes, the entire URL. Or the name of the github repository.

Comment: I have tried this     "dojo": "https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git",  but it get 1.10.4 instead I need to grab 1.11.0-pre... could you please provide me an example?Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Just tested - installed a pre-release version 1.11.0-pre. Try this URL: `https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#a275e8237cd8be0a4e3af4d229853f317bc56873`

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit, I see it get the files from git but at last moment it says EMALFORMED: failed to read ...... bower.json - Unexpected token }   do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890694/emalformed-failed-to-read-bower-json-on-bower-install-requirejs-text

Comment: thanks for your time please add your answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible use github as dependence:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#a275e8237cd8be0a4e3af4d229853f317bc56873"
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls