# VS 2013 Bower EMALFORMED bower.json

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bower

I'm trying to use Bower on Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5) along with Grunt, using [the Task Runner explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708). I've previously used Bower on its own so the whole set-up looked rather straightforward.
However, when using the following `bower.json`:

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "*"
    }
}
```

I get the following error, note that the unexpected token seems to be blank (this is not a copy-paste issue):

```
Executing  

bower                       EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Directory\bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token
```

The JSON seems to be valid, what could the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169387/emalformed-error-when-trying-to-register-bower-json-file/) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578596/bower-malformed/22579373#22579373): Visual Studio is writing a byte order mark, an invisible unicode character, to the beginning of the document.

To resolve the issue you can either use a different editor or change the file saving setting to exclude the symbol.

To do the latter, choose `File - Advanced Save Options` and choose `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001` as the encoding.