# node.js npm install error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I know this topic has come up many times,  but none of those solves my problem.  I am implementing a mean stack.  That needs these dependencies.

This is my package.json file that I am using.

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Video streaming application",
    "author": "First Last",
    "contributors": [{
        "name": "First Last",
        "email": "email@email.com"
    }],
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node bin/www.js"},
    "main": "bin/www.js",
    "keywords":[    
        "webrtc",
        "keyword2",
        "streaming",
        "video"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.2.0",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.8.11",
        "socket.io": "~1.2.1",
        "angular": "~1.3.7",
        "node-uuid": "~1.4.0"
    },
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

This is the errors I am getting when using the: "npm install" command.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 error Failed to parse json
6 error Unexpected token }
7 error File: C:\Users\name\Desktop\htdocs\package.json
8 error Failed to parse package.json data.
8 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
8 error
8 error This is not a bug in npm.
8 error Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
9 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
10 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
11 error cwd C:\Users\name\Desktop\htdocs
12 error node -v v0.10.33
13 error npm -v 1.4.28
14 error file C:\Users\name\Desktop\htdocs\package.json
15 error code EJSONPARSE
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You sure that's the exact file content you're using? It validates fine, at least for me.

Comment: Save package.json without UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: As Gergo said. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966959/28779

Comment: My notepad is already set to UTF-8 without BOM.  So this is not the issue. @GergoErdosi

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how I would get this to work on windows 8,  notepad++.  Today was the first day that it ever failed me.  Now I know that linux is the light and windows is just a false hope.  That being said.  I just got on my linux box.

Wrote the exact same file in vi and it worked.
Saved it,  tranfered it to windows and it worked.