# How does string encoding work in JavaScript program text?

Tags: javascript

ECMAScript [treats strings](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) as UTF-16.

If I write a program in my text editor, I assume the most-likely default encoding will be UTF-8.

```
console.log('')
```

So how does this "work"? Does it work because UTF-16 is directly compatible with UTF-8, which, in turn, is directly compatible with ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [section 10.1, *Source Text*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-source-text):

> ECMAScript code is expressed using Unicode. ECMAScript source text is
>   a sequence of code points. All Unicode code point values from U+0000
>   to U+10FFFF, including surrogate code points, may occur in source text
>   where permitted by the ECMAScript grammars. The actual encodings used
>   to store and interchange ECMAScript source text is not relevant to
>   this specification. Regardless of the external source text encoding, a
>   conforming ECMAScript implementation processes the source text as if
>   it was an equivalent sequence of *SourceCharacter* values, each
>   *SourceCharacter* being a Unicode code point.

Comment: So JavaScript engines typically have within them a text encoding detection capability, that permits either conversion of source text to UTF-16, or the treatment of differently encoded source text as UTF-16?

Comment: @52d6c6af JS engines just have an unicode sequence input, they don't have any encoding detection. That's part of the embedding, e.g. the HTTP code in the browser and [for Node.js I actually have no idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10125141/1048572). The unicode sequence is fed to the parser, which [constructs `String` values from literals](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-literals-string-literals) (which includes things like converting escape sequences).